# Child StatefulWidget doesn't use parameter values from parent widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make an editable text field which will show an *Edit* button only when a parameter is provided (if no value provided, it will only show a `SelectableText`).

EditableText field will be used in a parent widget which in this example is my `SubjectPage`. `SubjectPage` has default values for the `_currentUserRole` and `_isUserLoggedIn` fields but on initialization the values are read from local storage and I expect the values to be used in `EditableTextfield` and then make it show the *Edit* button. When I debug the application, the values seem to be read correctly but for some reason the `EditableTextfield` widget doesn't use the new values.

What am I doing wrong?

```
// ignore: must_be_immutable
class SubjectPage extends StatefulWidget {
  Subject? subject;
  final String subjectId;
  SubjectPage({super.key, required this.subjectId, this.subject});

  @override
  State<SubjectPage> createState() => _SubjectPageState();
}

class _SubjectPageState extends State<SubjectPage> {
  List<dynamic> _relatedUsers = [];
  Subject? _subject;
  TokenRole _currentUserRole = TokenRole.standard;
  bool _isUserLoggedIn = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _subject = widget.subject;
    fetchDataFromApi();
  }

  Future fetchDataFromApi() async {
    try
    {
      dynamic subjectJsonData;
      if(_subject == null || _subject?.title == null || _subject?.description == null)
      {
        String subjectUrl = "${ApiConfig.apiUrl()}subject/${widget.subjectId}";
        final http.Response response0 = await http.get(Uri.parse(subjectUrl));
        subjectJsonData = json.decode(response0.body);
      }

      await readUserData();

      setState(() {
      });

    } catch (err) { print(err); }
  }

  Future readUserData() async {
    // Get current user's role - if admin, should be able to edit content.
    _isUserLoggedIn = await UserService.isUserLoggedIn();
    _currentUserRole = await UserService.readUserRole();
  }

  Future<bool> updateSubjectTitle(String newTitle) async {
    _subject?.title = newTitle;
    try{
      // if(subject!=null) { ApiComms.updateSubject(subject!); }
    }
    catch(e) {
      print(e);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: schemeBackgroundColor,

      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: 200, maxWidth: 1000),
          child: ListView(children: [

            // title
            Align(alignment: Alignment.centerLeft, child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0, right: 30.0, top: 20, bottom: 10),
              child:

              EditableTextfield(
                displayText: "${widget.subject?.title}",
                displayTextStyle: styleTextHeader,
                isUserAdmin: _currentUserRole==TokenRole.admin,
                onUpdateText: updateSubjectTitle,
              ),
            )),

          ]),
        ),
      )
      )
    ;

  }
}
```

the `EditableTextfield` code:

```
// ignore: must_be_immutable
class EditableTextfield extends StatefulWidget {
  final String displayText;
  TextStyle? displayTextStyle;
  final Function(String) onUpdateText;
  bool isUserAdmin;

  EditableTextfield({super.key,
    required this.displayText,
    this.displayTextStyle,
    required this.onUpdateText,
    this.isUserAdmin = false
    });

  @override
  State<EditableTextfield> createState() => _EditableTextfieldState();
}

class _EditableTextfieldState extends State<EditableTextfield> {
  String _displayText = "";
  TextStyle? _displayTextStyle;
  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  final bool obscureText = false;
  bool _isUserAdmin = false;
  bool _iAmInEditMode = false;

  final titleController = TextEditingController();
  final descriptionController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    _displayText = widget.displayText;
    _controller.text = _displayText;
    _displayTextStyle = widget.displayTextStyle ??= styleTextParagraph;
    _isUserAdmin = widget.isUserAdmin;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void onEditOrSavePressed() {
    if(_iAmInEditMode) {
      widget.onUpdateText(_controller.text);
      _displayText = _controller.text;
    }
    _iAmInEditMode = !_iAmInEditMode;
    setState(() {
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return
      Row(children: <Widget>[
          _iAmInEditMode?
            Expanded(child: InputField(controller: _controller, hintText: "", obscureText: obscureText))
            : SelectableText(_displayText, style: _displayTextStyle),
          if(_isUserAdmin) OrdinaryButton.overrideOnPressed(onPressed: onEditOrSavePressed, text: !_iAmInEditMode? "Edit" : "Save"),
        ]
      );
  }
}
```